# glibc detected free() Invalid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, glibc

So, I have looked through COUNTLESS other posts about similar topics, and none of them have been able to give me a satisfactory answer.  I am writing a doubly linked list program, and when I create a Queue object in the driver file, I get this error:

> *** glibc detected *** ./driver.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400773 ***

All it is doing is calling on the constructor(Literally the only code in Main()):

```
Queue341<int> myQueue;
```

Here is the constructor:

```
template <class T>
Queue341<T>::Queue341()
{
}
```

All the proper header files are include, guarded, etc.  I just do not understand this error... I NEVER even USE free()!!!

Edit:
Here is the Destructor code:
template

```
Queue341<T>::~Queue341(){
  Clear();
}
```

And here is Clear():

```
template <class T>
bool Queue341<T>::Clear(){
  Node341<T> *current, *next;

  current = this->m_head;
  while (current != NULL){
    next = current->m_next;
    delete current;
    current = next;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a destructor? The destructor for the Queue will run once the queue object goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes, there is.  So, you're saying that as soon as main ends, the destructor will get called?

Comment: Yes, it will. Can you post the destructor as well?

Comment: Sure, give me one second.

Comment: There we go! What do you think?

Comment: My guess is that you never initialize `m_head` to anything so when you set `current = this->m_head`, `current` isn't a `nullptr` and the memory it points to gets deleted even though it was never allocated. This would certainly be an issue. So try setting `m_head = nullptr` in your constructor and see what happens.

Comment: hmmmm.... Interesting point.  I will look into that more, thanks!

Comment: So, I went ahead and set m_head=NULL, and recompiled and ran the code and it did NOT yell at me.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me figure that out!

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

> I just do not understand this error
>   All it is doing is calling on the constructor(Literally the only code in Main()):

You've corrupted heap somewhere else. In `C++`, if you have global variables of class type, lots of code executes before (and after) `main`.

> I NEVER even USE free()

But you use `delete` which calls `free`.

Run your program under valgrind, and it will tell you *exactly* where your problem is.

Comment: I have no global variables.

Comment: And I have tried using Valgrind, but it didn't really help.  Now, this may be my fault with misreading it

Comment: That other question you said this was a duplicate of did not help at all, by the way.